# Room - миграция в debug, без смены версии

Tags: android, android-room, room

Разбираюсь с миграцией в Room - источником использую [ресурс](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/540-urok-12-migracija-versij-bazy-dannyh.html). Сама миграция не сложная но вот как сделать так что бы во время отладки не было необходимости писать миграцию и в ручную удалять БД? Есть решение, делаю это так:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDatabase(app: App): AppDatabase = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Room.databaseBuilder(app, AppDatabase::class.java, "database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
} else {
    Room.databaseBuilder(app, AppDatabase::class.java, "database").build()
}
```

`.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` - этот метод по сути пересоздаёт БД при необходимости миграции, но одной маленькой проблемкой, ему требуется постоянно менять версию БД. Мне же в данной ситуации было бы лучше её просто пересоздать с существующей версией. Кто может подсказать как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Что-то менять в коде всё равно придётся, иначе никак не определить, нужно ли пересоздать/обновить базу или оставить существующую. Так почему бы не версию? Или вы хотите при каждом запуске сносить базу и создавать заново?

Comment: Нет, если бы я так и хотел, то тут без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Room создает 3 файла, содержащие в имени имя базы, по пути стандартному для бд. Что-то вроде `/data/data/app_name/databases`. Полный путь можно получить из `context.getDatabasePath`. В том месте, где инициализируете базу, перед этим проверяете `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, если оно тру - удаляете файлы до инициализации и база создастся чистая без смены версии

Comment: Как мне определить что какой то из моих объектов изменился, чтобы  словить ошибку и выполнить данное действие?